# AQGridview - Loading images from web (URL)

Tags: image, ipad, loading, aqgridview

I'm new in iPad development. I'm using AQGridView to build my first ipad app. With the following code, I'm trying to load images from web URLs into each cell of the grid but, when I scroll down and come back up the images are not the same like they should, so they reload to display the good one.

Here's the code I use to load my images.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgPath]]];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        _imageView.image = img;
        [self setNeedsLayout];
    });
});
```

I think the problem comes from here, when calling the dispatch_get_main_queue(). But I dunno how to fix that. If someone has an idea it would for sure help me!

Much thanks in advance!

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Apple has a demo of a clean solution to exactly this problem in [LazyTableImages](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html)